# Python name verification lopp

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, verification

I'm trying to make a loop that keeps asking a user for input until they enter a string and store this agains a variable 'name'.

I can get the while loop working but don't know how to store the answer against the variable when the user gets it correct.

```
name = raw_input("name: ")

def check_name(name):
  x = 0
  while x == 0:
    if name.isalpha():
      return name
      x += 1
    else:
      raw_input("You need to enter your name: ")

check_name(name)
print name
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `name = raw_input("You need to enter your name: ")`

The full code would be:

```
name = raw_input("name: ")

def check_name(name):
  while True:
    if name.isalpha():
      return name
    else:
      name = raw_input("You need to enter your name: ")

name = check_name(name)
print name
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried the 'name' bit.

I think it was the use of the x = 0 that was causing the problems.

Your True method works.